# docker run fails with /bin/sh:0 -c requires an argument

Tags: docker, build, gcloud

I am trying to run a docker image

Dockerfile

```
FROM marketplace.gcr.io/google/ubuntu1804:latest
MAINTAINER Vinay Joseph (vinay.joseph@microfocus.com)
LABEL ACI_COMPONENT="License Server"
EXPOSE 20000/tcp

#Install Unzip
RUN apt-get install unzip

#Unzip License Server to /opt/MicroFocus
RUN mkdir /opt/MicroFocus
RUN cd /opt/MicroFocus

#Download the License Server
RUN curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/software-idol-21/LicenseServer_12.1.0_LINUX_X86_64.zip
RUN chmod 777 LicenseServer_12.1.0_LINUX_X86_64.zip
RUN unzip LicenseServer_12.1.0_LINUX_X86_64.zip
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/xxxx/idol-licenseserver', '.']
images:
- 'gcr.io/xxxx/idol-licenseserver'
```

The message i get is

```
docker run gcr.io/xxxx/idol-licenseserver
```

> /bin/sh: 0: -c requires an argument

Comment: could you share that command which you run container?

Comment: docker run gcr.io/xxxx/idol-licenseserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your `Dockerfile`

### First

```
RUN apt-get install unzip
```

A good practice is to perform an `update` before installing packages, otherwise you could fall into situation with missing package lists.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ...
```

### Second

```
RUN mkdir /opt/MicroFocus
RUN cd /opt/MicroFocus
```

This is mistake because `cd` doesn't work between layers (different `RUN` commands). What you wanted is achieved with single `WORKDIR` command

```
WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus
```

### Third

The error message that you are facing means that base image is configured with something like `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]` therefore expecting you to provide initial command line when launching this image. You have to define the proper startup command and append it to your command after image name.

Comment: Where exactly do I append the command after the image name? Is it in the dockerfile or at the docker run command?

Comment: `docker run ... <image_name> <ARGUMENTS GO HERE>`

Answer (score 0):

`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]` is the default entrypoint in every Dockerfile if you do not choose your own entrypoint. If you run the Dockerfile, add a command of your choice that you would like to run. At best just try `bash`:

```
docker run -it gcr.io/xxxx/idol-licenseserver bash
```

Without adding any command, the container does not know what to run in the command line but still starts the bash (sh in this case) to run something, waiting for a command = `-c requires an argument`.